# Angular - Allow Enter Key on textarea but not in formGroup

Tags: angular, formgroups

The user needs to use the **enter key** on the **textarea** but not in formGroup.

Heres my ***html***

```
<form [formGroup]="interventionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">

    <textarea class="focus-input gap-textarea"></textarea>

<button type="submit" class="btn teq-btn">{{ lang.trans('send') }}</button>

</form>
```

The **formGroup** its not getting submited by pressing the **enter key**, but the **textareas** are getting affected to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use $event.stopPropagation() instead of $event.preventDefault().
Your code should look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="interventionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" (keydown.enter)="$event.stopPropagation()">

    <textarea class="focus-input gap-textarea"></textarea>

<button type="submit" class="btn teq-btn">{{ lang.trans('send') }}</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this answers your question, but also for anyone else coming across this, if you want `keydown.enter` to work in a `textarea` but not submit the form in other places, the following worked for me:

```
<form (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
  <textarea (keydown.enter)="$event.stopPropagation()"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This prevents `keydown.enter` from submitting the form:
`<form (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">`

This allows enter to still create new lines in the `textarea`:
`<textarea (keydown.enter)="$event.stopPropagation()">`

An aside: the form being submitted on pressing enter is only the default behaviour when the submit button is present:
`<button type="submit">Submit</button>`

it may be that you don't need/want this in the first place, so you can just change it to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use a custom directive to manage the Enter key press, ignoring it for textareas:

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[enterKeyPress]'
})
export class EnterKeyPressDirective {
  @Output()
  public enterKeyPress = new EventEmitter<void>();

  @HostListener('keyup.enter', ['$event'])
  public onKeyUpEnter(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const targetTagName = (event.target as HTMLElement).tagName.toLowerCase();

    if (targetTagName !== 'textarea') {
      this.enterKeyPress.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

So you can use the form safely, also with textareas inside:

```html
<form (enterKeyPress)="submit()">
  <input type="text" />
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```